# Can we use { to declare e variable variable?

Tags: php, variables

I have a piece of code which I a trying to shorten using variable variable, wanted to check if this is a valid code.

Original code:

```
$town = ( $_POST['town'] ) ;
$county = ($_POST['county'] ) ;

// Update town user meta
if ( !empty( $town ) )
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'town', $town);

// Delete town user meta
else
    delete_user_meta( $user_id, 'town' );

//Update county user meta
if ( !empty( $county ) )
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'county', $county);

// Delete county user meta
else
    delete_user_meta( $user_id, 'county' );
```

Shortened code :

```
$fields = array("town","county");
foreach ($fields as $field) {
${$field} = $_POST[$field];
    if ( !empty( $field ) ) { update_user_meta( $user_id, "$field", ${$field}); } else { delete_user_meta( $user_id, "$field" ); }  
}
```

Without the shortened code, we can accommodate more variables, which is the goal.

Thanks for your time.

**EDIT**

Special thanks to all the negative voters. My last post here got 7 negative votes, here its 2 only so far. Com'n guys, break my last record.

On a more serious note, there must be a stricter policy by Stackoverflow about negative voting and there must be a scrutiny on such votes by other people - I feel, random mass negative votes like these can be highly demoralizing.

Comment: Hint: [*use an array*](http://oreilly.com/catalog/progphp/chapter/ch05.html) - just as $_POST is an array, follow through with utilizing a collection.

Comment: Don't bother setting a variable! Just use `$_POST[$field]` in your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
   if ( !empty( $value) ) { update_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $value); } 
   else { delete_user_meta( $user_id, $key); } 
}
```

Or something along those lines.

EDIT: But if you really need to define a list of fields you could do

```
$fields = array("town","county");

foreach($fields as $field){
       if ( !empty($_POST[$field]) ) { update_user_meta( $user_id, $field, $_POST[$field]); } 
       else { delete_user_meta( $user_id, $field ); } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have an array you can use:

```
foreach( $_POST as $field => $value ){
  if ( !empty( $value ) ) update_user_meta( $user_id, $field, $value);
}
```

However, you need to run validation on the POST data and make sure you guard against sql injection

Comment: Ideally the framework providing `update_user_meta` is already designed as to be safe from sql injection.